# Access Calling Global Variable from Combo Box in DoCmd.RunSQL

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, combobox, global-variables

Please help me with my latest attempt to learn VBA.  I'm building a database in Access 2007.

When the database starts up, there is a form with a combo box where people pick their name then hit a button.  I made a module called Globals to store the combobox choice as a variable.  here is the code, please tell me if it's wrong!

```
Public Function GetAssocName() As String
        AssocName = Forms!frm_ChooseAssoc!ChooseAssocComboBox.Value
End Function
```

It's my understanding that this will store the choice as a variable for **as long as the database is open, no matter if the form is open or closed**.  Regardless, I have chosen to do Me.Visible=FALSE instead of closing the form.

Then, I have a sub that appends some stuff to two tables in the database.  Here is my code for that, please tell me if it's wrong or bad!

```
Public Sub Add2TablesButton_Click()
    '
    Dim AreYouSuremsgbox As String
    '
    AreYouSuremsgbox = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to do this?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Are you sure?")
    '
    If (AreYouSuremsgbox = vbYes) Then
        DoCmd.Hourglass True
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_OrderArchive ([Loan#], OrderDate, Rush, Associate) " & _
                     "SELECT qry_Orders.[Loan #], Date(), qry_Orders.Rush, AssocName " & _
                     "FROM qry_Orders WHERE qry_Orders.[Order Placed in OrderApp]=TRUE;"

        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_CE ([Loan#], [InvLoan#], InvCode, BorrowerName, Status, Rush) " & _
                     "SELECT qry_Orders.[Loan #], qry_Orders.[Inv #], qry_Orders.[Inv Code], " & _
                     "qry_Orders.Borrower, qry_Orders.Status, qry_Orders.Rush " & _
                     "FROM qry_Orders WHERE qry_Orders.[Order Placed in OrderApp]=TRUE;"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        DoCmd.Hourglass False
        MsgBox "Done!", vbOKOnly, "Done!"
    ElseIf (AreYouSuremsgbox = vbNo) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Please notice the first DoCmd.RunSQL where it says AssocName.  I want it to call the global variable and append it into the table.  But every time I test this thing, it asks for me to physically type in AssocName.

I've tried tons of syntax things, googled all day, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks you so much for your time.

Comment: First off, you don't show the definition for 'AssocName'. Create a stand-alone module and use 'Global AssocName as string'. Next, your function to return the name is wrong. It should be: GetAssocName = AssocName   (or you can reference Forms!frm_ChooseAssoc!ChooseAssocComboBox.Value). Finally, change the Dim of AreYouSuremsgbox to INTEGER

Comment: Thank you, when I do this I get an error Invalid Outside Procedure when trying to do the Global AssocName as String thing. And it highlights the Forms! part of AssocName = Forms!frm_ChooseAssoc!ChooseAssocComboBox.Value

Comment: Do I just put Global AssocName as string in the module and nothing else, and then in the code for the button put the form value to AssocName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code window, click 'Insert | Module' and past in the following:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Global AssocName  As String

Public Function GetAssocName() As String
    GetAssocName = AssocName  
End Function
```

Then in your form that has the username combobox, after the user selects their name.

```
AssocName = Me.ChooseAssocComboBox
```

Then change the following line from:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_OrderArchive ( [Loan#], OrderDate, Rush, Associate ) " & _
     "SELECT qry_Orders.[Loan #], Date(), qry_Orders.Rush, AssocName FROM qry_Orders 
     "WHERE qry_Orders.[Order Placed in OrderApp]=TRUE;"
```

To: (assume you want the current user name?)

```
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_OrderArchive ( [Loan#], OrderDate, Rush, Associate ) " & _
     "SELECT qry_Orders.[Loan #], Date(), qry_Orders.Rush, '" & GetAssocName & "' FROM qry_Orders 
     "WHERE qry_Orders.[Order Placed in OrderApp]=TRUE;"
```

Comment: It seems to be working!!!! Thank you so much.  What I'm taking away from this is that the function in the module needs to be there because you need a function to access the variable, and I need to concatenate a function into an SQL statement, I can't just put it in there.  Let me know if I'm not understanding that correctly.  Again, thank you!!!!

Comment: (1) Original code for 'GetAssocName' 'gets' the value from the combobox on form and saves into variable 'AssocName' - but would not provide that value to anyone else. Rather than debate the meaning of 'GetAssocName' (either gets from form and saves, or gets the stored value and returns to me), I took the latter because your function was designed to return a string (thus the reason to set the function name to the value); (2) AssocName as coded in your SQL would have just resulted in it asking for a parameter because it would be treated as just that. You needed to supply the value - delimited.